# Android Emulator not running

Tags: xamarin.android, android-emulator, visual-studio-2019

I am new to mobile development. Trying to follow tutorialspoint for my first xamarin android app. The emulator fails to start.

Emulator is set to use android 9.0. When running directly from Tools -> Android -> Android Device Manager, emulator runs but crashes. When running from Visual Studio debug, comes up with following error.

"Starting emulator testdevice ...
Checking HAXM compatibility.
Emulator testdevice cannot be started.
Runtime checks completed
NuGet package restore canceled."

where 'testdevice' is the name of my emulator.

Have been on Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager, then on Tools tab. Then Under Extras, I've selected the HAXM installer and clicked apply changes.

I've been looking online but nothing seems to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to verify haxm support.  On a command prompt type

```
sc query intelhaxm
```

For more info, refer to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows

Comment: Yes, I did this. HAXM wasn't installed. Downloaded the HAXM files and then found out intel vt-x wasnt enabled so had to do that.